# Ubuntu 15.10 boot loader for dualboot with OS X El Capitan

Tags: dual-boot, mac, bootloader

I want to install Ubuntu 15.10 for dualboot with OS X. I made the partitions (Ext2 for /boot, Ext4 for / and /home and SWAP) with gparted from the live stick; 
starting the installation Ubuntu doesn't 'see' OS X, it offers only the manual way. There I am not sure where to put the boot loader, on /dev/sda, or better /dev/sda1 which is the EFI partition (from rEFInd??) or somewhere after the OS X partitions?

Answer (score 0):

You should select the partition that you are installing Ubuntu for i.e. the same ext4 partition that that you are mounting root (/) to. You shouldn't need a separate /boot partition; make sure you have properly installed rEFIned (i.e. disable SIP first before installing).